# How to call prop function from setup in vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-props

I have the next code:

HTML:

```
<p @click="changeForm">Iniciar sesion</p>
```

JS

```
export default {
   name: "Register",
   props: {
      changeForm: Function,
   },
   setup() {
      //How can i call props changeForm here???
   }
}
```

How can i call my props function from JS? The other way around is to trigger click on my p element, is that possible?

I am using vue 3. I have tested with this.changeForm and props.changeForm with no luck.

Comment: I don't think changeForm should be a prop, it's a method: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/data-methods.html

Comment: @R_Ice It's ok to use function (and method) props

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `setup` function receives `props` as its first argument:

```js
export default {
   name: "Register",
   props: {
     changeForm: Function,
   },
   setup(props) {            // receive `props` argument
     props.changeForm();     // use it to access `changeForm`
   }
}
```

Comment: How do I access props from a `method` in Vue3?
`this`, `props` nor `$props` nor `this.$props` do work.

Comment: @ElectRocnic - If you're using the Options API (i.e. a `methods` block), it's the same as Vue 2:  `this.myPropName`.  Otherwise, your method would be in `setup` and you'd use the format above.

Comment: Yes I found it afterwards. What nobody told me is that I now have to define the `methods` WITHIN the `setup()` method and RETURN them in a `{ method1, method2, prop1, prop2, etc. }` block from within the `setup()`. This completely confused me.

Comment: Typescript will complain: `TS2339: property 'changeForm' does not exist on type Readonly { changeForm: { type: FunctionConstructor } ...`. Is there any workaround?